# Стоит ли когда либо использовать #include <bits / stdc ++.h>?

Tags: c++, библиотеки

я вот только не давно узнал про заголовочный файл `#include <bits / stdc ++. H>` и зачал искать информацию по этой библиотеке .Все говорят что ее не рекомендуется использовать из за того что много мусора и долгая компиляция ,так какой смысл этой библиотеки ?Или она создана для "ленивого программирования"?

Comment: Это не библиотека, а внутренний заголовочный файл в некоторых компиляторах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кроме медленной компиляции, минус этого файла в том, что он нестандартный. Он есть только в GCC (а точнее в его стандартной библиотеке С++, libstdc++).

Обычно его используют для "ленивого программирования", да.

Но сделан он был для использования в качестве PCH (precompiled header, предварительно компилируемый заголовочный файл - погулилите термин). Хотя даже для этой цели использовать его сомнительно - я бы использовал свои PCH.